# Parallelogram angles proof

Tags: geometry

In parallelogram $ABCD$, $\angle A$ is sharp.Point $E$ is in the middle of $BC.$ Point $F$ on $AD$ is in a such position that $EF=DE$.Point $G$- is a base of height from point $D$ on $AB.$ Prove that $\angle AGF= \angle CED.$

Because of their awkward position in parallelogram it is kind of complex to prove that.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Added: The combined effect of (1) E being the midpoint of BC; and (2) $\angle AGD$ being $90^0$ ensures that G is part of the red circle.

In the figure, all angles that are red dotted are equal.

$\angle AGF = 90^0 + (red)dotted$

After dropping the perpendicular $EH$ to $AF$, $\angle CED$ is also $90^0 + (red)dotted$

Comment: Thanks. That looks right,but can you help me to understand how you have got to such equality of red dotes angles?

Comment: @jackjones The one at G is equal to the one at K (angles in the same segment) and is equal to half of $\angle DEF$ (angle at center = 2 times angles at circumference). But $\angle DEF$ is bisected by the dotted line that goes through the center and perpendicular to the chord DF.